# Sorting a 2-D Array by Copying it to a 1-D Array, the output is correct but the iterations are repeating

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

When I sort a 2-D Array which is an argument to a function by Copying it to a 1-D Array, the output is correct but the iterations are repeating. Is my approach correct? I have used an Array "Sort" to copy both the unsorted Arrays & then sort this result set Array.

[image: Image of the logic and the output]

```
package learningJava;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class VarArgDemoThree 
{

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        //First one D unsorted Array
        int a[]= {10,2,56,17,81,92};

        //Second one D unsorted Array
        int b[]= {12,77,22,98,101,6};

        //Static method Sort which to which both Arrays a & b are passed
        Sort(a,b);
    }

    //Definition of Static method Sort
    public static void Sort(int[]...x )//This method has a one d array as variable argument which is int[][] it get array (a[],b[])
    {

        //Declaring another one-d Sort of which the length is 12
        int[] Sort = new int[x[0].length+x[1].length];

        //Copying the one D array at location x[0] to another Array Sort using System.arraycopy
        System.arraycopy(x[0], 0, Sort, 0, x[0].length);

        //Copying the one D array at location x[1] to another Array Sort using System.arraycopy
        System.arraycopy(x[1], 0, Sort, x[0].length, x[1].length);

       //Sorting the Elements of the Array Sort 
        for(int i=0;i<Sort.length;i++)
        {
            int flag=0;
            for(int j=i+1;j<Sort.length;j++)
            {
                if(Sort[i]>Sort[j])
                {
                    int temp = Sort[i];
                    Sort[i]  = Sort[j];
                    Sort[j]  = temp;
                    flag=1;
                }
            }

            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Sort));
            System.out.println();
            if(flag==0)
            {
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing that loop more than it is needed.

just see the code below:

```
for(int i=0;i<Sort.length;i++) // line a
    {
        int flag=0;
        for(int j=i+1;j<Sort.length;j++) // line b
        {
            if(Sort[i]>Sort[j])
            {
                int temp = Sort[i];
                Sort[i]  = Sort[j];
                Sort[j]  = temp;
                flag=1;
            }
        }

        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Sort)); // line c
        System.out.println();
```

in "line a" the loop is repeating until `i == Sort.length`.

in "line b" the loop is starting from `j = i + 1` till `j == Sort.length`.

it is obvious that the last time the inner loop in "line b" does not run but "line c" that is printing `Sort` will run. that's why you're printing the array one extra time.
imagine the inner loop started from `Sort.length + 1` till `Sort.length`.

to avoid that you would better to change the first loop to `i < Sort.length - 1`.

some more matters (which are optional):

- why do you need `flag` ? you are looping till the end.
- try to start the name of fields and local variables in lower case. for example use `sort` instead of `Sort`.
- you can use `System.out.print("something")` and empty `System.out.println()` together, like `System.out.println("something")`.

Comment: Thanks Majid for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
i<Sort.length-1 for the outer loop only works thanks..

    int a[]= {10,6,18,23,97,188,67,45,52};
    int b[]= {4,15,28,77,60,71,90,33,24};    

    for(int i=0;i<Sort.length-1;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=i+1;j<Sort.length;j++)
                    {
                        if(Sort[i]>Sort[j])
                        {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
                            int temp = Sort[i];
                            Sort[i]  = Sort[j];
                            Sort[j]  = temp;
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Sort));
                }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jB1G.png
```